# NServiceBus Send and Received in a Single Process

Tags: nservicebus

I have NServiceBus running in a single process, but I would like to send Message A, but receive only Message B.  However, I think because Message Endpoint Mappings are used for both sending and receiving, the process is trying to handle both messages - A and B.  Any way around this issue?  Both messages go onto the same queue, based on the fact that a single process can only listen to a single queue NSB limitation.

Comment: I think more info is needed to be able to help.  Are these commands or events?  Are A and B different message *types*?  Do you have a handler for Message A in your process, and if not, what do you mean that your process is receiving it?

Comment: A and B are different .NET types,s some commands some events, the problem exists in all cases.  I have handlers loaded for just Message B, since I receive only , and send only A.  So, when my A message is received, I get "no handler is registered"

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283490/nservicebus-warning-no-handlers-could-be-found-for-message-type

Comment: Can you share the code and the config you have? 
to what endpoint are you sending message A? 
can you describe the use case a bit more please?

Comment: Phil's link is correct.  It speaks to another limitation - single process can only listen to a single queue.  This limitation is what led me to the current question.

Comment: I do not have config files - all configuration is done in code to promote central management of all configuration.

Comment: A little more on use case.  I am now using Send() overload that takes destination as a paramater, so I can derive the destination based on bus instance configuration.  In other words, the code looks like the following.  Is (this.Mode = ModeA) this.Bus>Send(destinationForModeA, message).  I configure input queue in code as well using Condfigure.DegineEndpointName(determineBasedOnModeEndoiintName).  I got the demo to work, but I feel that it took a lot more effort than it should because I cannot listen to multiple endpoints from single instance and filter messages for each endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two different AppDomains.

The statement

> a single process can only listen to a single queue

Is not actually correct. It is more correct to say

> a single appdomain can only listen to a single queue

Since you can have multiple appdomains per process you could have a since processes listening to multiple queues